# JavaFX WebView contextmenu unavailable

Tags: javafx, webview

I have setContextMenuEnabled(true), but it doesn't work, no context menu is available!

```
    FXCanvas canvas = new FXCanvas(composite, SWT.EMBEDDED);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    webView = new WebView();
    webView.setContextMenuEnabled(true);
    root.getChildren().add(webView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    canvas.setScene(scene);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is FXCanvas, I guess You are trying to embed JavaFX component into SWT application. I think you should mention about this in your question.

Comment: yes,it's in eclipse RCP